# Sharepoint SPFile - Get File Type

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007, accessibility

I am using SPFile to display a list of files and I want to display the type of file, as a string, so PDF, Word, Excel etc.

Looks like:
FileABC                                PDF
FileDEF                                Excel

I have got the icon back using "ListItem.File.IconUrl", ListItem is SPListItem

But I would like to get the file type as a name. It must work out the file type so the correct image can be displayed but I want to display the words too (for accessibility)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply take the "FileLeafRef" attribute which contains filename + local path, create an `System.IO.FileInfo` object out of that and then access the `.Extension` property:

```
System.IO.FileInfo inf = new System.IO.FileInfo("/images/files/something.gif");
Console.WriteLine(inf.Extension); //outputs .gif
```

I believe it will not be that easy to find matching program for each extension (you mention you need "Excel" not "xls". So, the easiest way, i think, is to create a dictionary of known extensions. Something like this:

```
System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary oDict = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary();
oDict.Add(".xls", "Excel");
oDict.Add(".xlsx", "Excel");
oDict.Add(".doc", "Word");
```

and then:

```
oDict[inf.Extension]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the extension from the listitem as
ListItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.DocIcon]